# Android APK size too large

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, deployment, filesize

I am done writing my application and I want to deploy it on the production server and I found out the APK size is too large. It takes up to 90MB and I do not consider that as a good thing. After setting Linking Options to SDK Assemblies only, it reduced to 85MB which is not good either. Please How can I reduce the APK size to about 40MB or even 30MB Maximum?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/app-package-size

Comment: Check my blog here https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688

Comment: Here is a good reference.https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Comment: You should uncheck "use shared runtime" and "Enable developer instrumentation" in Android options.And also set linking to Sdk assemblies only

Answer (score 0):

These are a few solutions you can try to reduce the size of your APK

```
 1.Compress your drawables ( You can find many websites to compress images without quality change).
 2.Remove redundant assests and files.
 3.GOTO Analyse-->Inspect Code-->Whole project. It will scan your
 code,you can try to optimise it by No warnings and 0 erors.
 4.Remove unused dependencies in gradle.
```